# Can I access the content of Simdriveline components?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I am using Simdriveline components in Simscape. I would like to access the source code of these components. How can I do this?
For instance, I want to define a new `vehicle body` with more than 2 axes and different tire diameters.

Comment: [This](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151685-vehicle-body-block-additional-port) is a related question.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. Only the source code of the basic Simscape components is available to view and edit (after making your own copy). The source code of the add-on products, such as SimDriveline, is protected. However, the documentation for the block should provide all the necessary equations (but not the implementation in code).

Answer (score 0):

As [am304](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257388/am304) pointed out, it is only possible to access the source code of *Simscape* components, not of the extensions such as *SimMechanics*, *SimDriveline*, *SimHydraulics*, *SimElectronics*, *SimPowerSystems*.